# How can I animate the full-resolution image in an ImageView when using a ViewAnimator like ScaleAnimation?

Tags: java, android, imageview

Currently I am importing an image into an `ImageView` and displaying it at full device width and `wrapContent` for height. When I tap the image, I am using a `ScaleAnimation` to zoom in on it, and it all works great. The problem is that I'm scaling the cached bitmap that was scaled down to fit the device width.

For example a 1080p image when added onto my 720p device is definitely getting down-ressed (`layout_width=match_parent`) since when I click to zoom in, the device is zooming into the cached 720p bitmap version of my 1080p image. I'm purposely downloading a higher-resolution image so that it'll hold up to zooming, but I don't know how to force it to use the original image instead of the cached version.

Here's where I'm handling the zoom:

```
private void zoomIn(View v, int time){
    // initialize animations
    Animation scaleAnimation;
    imageCenter = new Point(imageView.getWidth() / 2, imageView.getHeight() / 2);

    // build animations
    scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(scaleMin,scaleMax,scaleMin,scaleMax, imageCenter.x, imageCenter.y);
    scaleAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);

    // build animation set
    AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(true);
    s.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
    s.setDuration(time);
    s.setFillAfter(true);
    s.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    v.startAnimation(s);
}
```

I am considering using a `ObjectAnimator` instead, but it seems a bit unecessary. Surely there's a way to just tell it to redraw using the full-resolution image when I animate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(scaleMin, scaleMax, scaleMin, scaleMax, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5);`

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting the same result: the cached 720p image getting zoomed instead of the original 1080p image :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it was because I was resizing the image via Picasso. When I sized it properly, it had no problems. I thought the GPU cached a bitmap at max visible res (so a 1080p image would be down-ressed to 720p on a 720p display) but I was wrong. The full 1080p image, even though it was shrunk, had all the detail of the full version.